# Apache 2.4.6 - ServerAlias wildcard, but %1 is not substituted

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

VirtualHost has got the following directives, but %0 and %1 are not getting the values. Is this a bug? Can we use %1 in any subsequent directives? What am I missing? Thanks!

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias *.www.example.com
```

Comment: ServerAlias requires a FQDN. Wildcards are not permitted within a FQDN. You need to have a ServerAlias line for each of your domains.

Comment: @AndreGelinas this is not true, you can use [wildcards no problem](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: Where and how are you using the substitutions ?